# SSRS : the operation has timed out

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I try to execute report viewer but does not work. So this is an error log message from ssrs log file.

ERROR: 
Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ClosingRegisteredStreamException: 
An error occurred closing a registered stream. ---> 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionException: 
A client has disconnected from the Report Server Web service application domain 
ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-4-131683910836410373. 
No corrective action is required. An error code has been submitted to ASP.NET to release the connection. 
The error code is 800708CA. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This network connection does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708CA)

Comment: Please check the report execution timeout:

  to do so, Go to report manager-> Site settings-> Report Timeout and select "Do not timeout report" or change the value of "Limit report processing to the following number of seconds".

Answer (score 0):

In the web config  set the http run time as

```
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout = "10800"/>
```